# MIPS problem with storing integer in an array

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm writing a program in MIPS language, which takes a number from the user to allocate an array with that number. Then, the user is asked to enter that many numbers to fill the array.

Comment: Just tag the architecture you need: don't simply use all possible MIPS tags.

Comment: @ErikEidt Isn't this allocating memory? : `li $v0, 9  # this is to allocate memory
    add $a0, $t3, $zero
    syscall`

Comment: Yes, you're right, I read that wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Looks like you're using the user's byte count found in `$s0`, for the add before `sw` where you mean to use `$s1`, the allocated pointer.  You should be able to find that using single step debugging, and seeing the wrong value being added there.
- You're using `$t1` both as a counter, and as a temporary register during the array indexing store, so that counter is getting wiped out.  Also can be seen by inspecting expected values during single step debugging.